# android.support.v4.content.FileProvider class not found in android Kitkat

Tags: android, android-camera, classnotfoundexception, android-fileprovider

I am using `FileProvider` in my app. As usual I declared `<Provider>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as below.

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.jk.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

When I run it on android device which has `lollipop` version it works fine. when I try it on `kitkat` version it shows following errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.jk.android.perfectphotoeditor2018, PID: 24992
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jk.android.perfectphotoeditor2018-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.jk.android.perfectphotoeditor2018-2, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5071)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4648)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4588)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jk.android.perfectphotoeditor2018-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.jk.android.perfectphotoeditor2018-2, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5056)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4648) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4588) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I had tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765211/android-fileprovider-class-not-found-in-release-builds) but it doesn't work for me. so, help me for solve this problem.

**build.gradle** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /* Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
    //    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file (`dependencies` section only) - also what is the complete stacktrace?

Comment: checkout edited question for dependencies i have used @pskink

Comment: "when I try it on kitkat version it shows ClassnotfoundException ." -- please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: checkout again...i edited questions as you said @CommonsWare

Comment: Do you have `multidex` enabled? If so, you may need to take some steps to ensure that `FileProvider` is in the main DEX file.

Comment: Yes, i have enabled multidex. which steps i should have to take? @CommonsWare

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep

Comment: so, i need to make 'multidex-config.txt' file in same directory as 'build.gradle' but i have two doubts.1) directory should be same as app level build.gradle or project level build.gradle? and 2) in 'multidex-config.txt' file i need to specify path of FileProvider class. so, what's the path of this file? is it 'android/support/v4/content/FileProvider'?@CommonsWare

Comment: i'd used 'android\support\v4\content\FileProvider.class' path and tried by putting this file in both build.gradle file directories alternatively but it doesn't work. is my file path wrong? @CommonsWare

Comment: I do not use multidex much, and so I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: it's ok! No problem and thanks for helping!

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200353/2504569

Answer (score 30):

If you have migrated to AndroidX you have to change the name in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`

That was the crash in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question, and this documentation solve my problem. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex[android multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

before android 5.0, you must use follow ways to multidex:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and then modify application, select any one of three ways:

if you not implement application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

if you have custom application, you can modify like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

if you have replace base application, you can modify like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base);
      MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

Hope this can solve you problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me (I've migrated to AndroidX):

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

in my project when set "multiDexEnabled" false, error fixed.
go to manifest and add

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled false
}}
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: you can delete it, also.

Comment: multiDexEnabled true is required to me, any other solution

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the intermediates folder.

[image: Click here for structure]

Answer (score 2):

After thorough reading of Android Multidex documentation, I found that there is one configuration we generally miss which causes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. If you have done regular multidex configuration for ***65K reference limit*** and and still unable to get rid of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` then you must follow these steps.

1. Create a file called **multidex-config.txt** at app level(same directory as the build.gradle file)
2. Add following line (the absolute class name for which you are getting exception)

   ```
   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
   ```
3. Modify your build.gradle as follow

   ```
   android {
       buildTypes {
           release {
               multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
               ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note : You can add it for specific build type or both by declaring it in `defaultConfig`.

#### What happens when you build a multidex enabled app :

> The Android build tools construct a primary DEX file (classes.dex) and supporting DEX files (classes2.dex, classes3.dex, and so on) as needed. The build system then packages all DEX files into your APK.
>
> At runtime, the multidex APIs use a special class loader to search all of the available DEX files for your methods (instead of searching only in the main classes.dex file).

#### Cause of Exception :

> When building each DEX file for a multidex app, the build tools perform complex decision-making to determine which classes are needed in the primary DEX file so that your app can start successfully. **If any class that's required during startup is not provided in the primary DEX file, then your app crashes with the error** `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

This shouldn't happen for code that's accessed directly from your app code because the build tools recognize those code paths, but it can happen when the code paths are less visible such as when a library you use has complex dependencies. For example, if the code uses introspection or invocation of Java methods from native code, then those classes might not be recognized as required in the primary DEX file.

So if you receive `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, then you must manually specify these additional classes as required in the primary DEX file by declaring them with the **multiDexKeepFile** (shown above) or the **multiDexKeepProguard** ([refer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#multidexkeepproguard-property)) property in your build type. If a class is matched in either the multiDexKeepFile or the multiDexKeepProguard file, then that class is added to the primary DEX file.

For complete documentation on multidex refer https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: This does not resolve the issue for me. Taking a closer look the exception asked for is a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` vs. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in this answer / on the multidex docs.

Comment: @martn_st Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Click to AndroidManifest.xml look at the bottom of the files page you gonna see "Text" and "Merged Manifes" then click to "Merged Manifest" -> Search for "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" then change it with "androidx.core.content.FileProvider"

Thats it, exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
```

to

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

tested and works for me

Answer (score -2):

[FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) was introduced with Android API Level 22 which is Lollipop, that is why you did not face the ClassNotFoundException when testing on a Lollipop device. Android Kitkat does not have the FileProvider class and hence you are facing the exception. If you are looking to access files [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222073/kitkat-storage-access-framework-specific-file-permission) should help you out

Comment: `FileProvider` is from the support libraries. It was added to the support libraries in version `22.1.0` of the libraries. It works back to at least Android 4.0.3.