# Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider"

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-fileprovider, androidx

I migrated my app to AndroidX and it's crashing on launch on API level 21. My application throws this exception:

```
10-08 09:42:50.930 11346-11346/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 11346
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.test-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.test-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is the `provider` definition in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

On the latest API level it works fine. Any suggestions would be useful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that this error came from incomplete configuration of MultiDex in your app. [Here](https://github.com/openfoodfacts/openfoodfacts-androidapp/issues/693) you may find the similar issue and [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-configure-multidex-in-an-application-android-f221198707ed) is an article answering it.

I suggest you to check the following (extending App class helped me):

Your Application class (App.class, for instance, if you use it) should extend from MultiDexApplication class:

```
public class BaseApplication extends MultiDexApplication {}
```

or if you don't use Application class check your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
        <application
            ...
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for such a precise solution.

Comment: Hi @akhirs ,My Application class is already extended but still i get this issues.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is outdated; use `androidx.multidex` for `androidx`:

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

Use the Jetifier when it still uses any `com.android.support` libraries:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Also add `multiDexEnabled true` inside `defaultConfig`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your React Native android project is not in **AndroidX** while `react-native-image-picker` is in an **AndroidX** environment; therefore, it is missing packages from the androidx package library.

Simple fix is adding the following lines to your `./android/gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If you have any existing RN libraries that uses old android packages, your project won't build since they will be missing once you updated your project.

A clever tool found here deals with RN libraries that uses old android packages and brings them up to date.

```
npm i --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
react-native run-android
```

All checked out and it's working on my end. Hope this helps anyone and please do share if it does.

Source https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1088#issuecomment-509755692

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It was NOT a ReactNative project.

Answer (score -1):

add below ndk lib support to your project if you have used the external library -

```
ndk
     {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"
     }
```

inside the default config of your app level build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig 
    {
        applicationId "org.comcast.net"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk
                {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"
                }
    }
```

it has solved my problem, hopefully it will solve at your end also.