# FileProvider class not found exception

Tags: android, crash, android-fileprovider

```
I am getting following error with android 10. Although i tried with my device having android 10, everything is working fine but Google  crashlytics showing number of crash. 

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.xyz-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/c-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/lib/arm64, /data/app-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/-MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/MraZIoKhOLuyDHnQOgA2Cg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7443)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6935)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6852)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:242)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7830)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at
```

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1040)

Comment: How does your manifest file look?

Comment: <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
        </provider>

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your provider in the AndroidManifest.xml file?
as it is said in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

If Yes, you will need to provide more information about how you work with the FileProvider class

Comment: Yes i have registered file provider in the manifest file. I am sharing a image with shareIntent downloaded from server. It is working with mostly device but for some device with Android 10 getting crash.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696574/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-content-fileprovider ?
It looks like you have some problems with MultiDex